# dealing with multiple $_POST coming from different objects

Tags: php, post

I have a form like this, with lots of checkboxes

```
<form action="myscript.php" method="post">
   <select name="myselect>
      <option value="1">option1</option>
      <option value="2">option2</option>
      <option value="3">option3</option>
      ...
   </select>
   <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="aaa"/>something1</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="aab"/>something2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="aac"/>something3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="aad"/>something4</li>
      ...
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

(number of select's options and number of checkboxes are not defined and can vary)
I can't figure out how to retrieve all the checkboxes $_POST values without "mixing" with my select value...

In a similar case, in which i had only lots of textboxes i did this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   ...
}
```

but in this case i had ONLY textboxes...

Comment: with the foreach cycle i could retrieve all the values, because were only key-value. in this case i need to separate select value from chexboxes values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkboxes won't submit *any* data unless they have a name. If you give them all the same name, then they will be grouped by any sane form data parser. In the case of PHP (which is overengineered for edge cases in that particular part of its design) the name has to end with `[]`.

Then you can:

```
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="aaa"/></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="aab"/></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="aac"/></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="aad"/></li>
```

And:

```
foreach($_POST['foo'] as $value) {
   ...
}
```

will loop over all the values of all the checked checkboxes (unchecked checkboxes will not be successful so won't be in the data).

Comment: i mistyped "value" with "name", sorry... but i think you just give me what i was looking for :D

Answer (score 2):

Your checkbox elements don't have `name`s. If a checkbox is unchecked the name will not appear in `$_POST`, if it is checked it will appear with the specified value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="aaa" value="1"/>
```

Should give you:

```
$_POST["aaa"] === "1";
```